# Neo4j - don't know how to improve cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this query returning very fast, 0.5 seconds and returning all 303 records expected. Note: "Woka" here means "Book".

```
MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author),
(l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w:Woka)-[u:INCLUDED]->(b:Bisac) 
WHERE (a.author_name = 'Camus, Albert') 
RETURN w.woka_id as woka_id, p.publisher_name as publisher_name, w.woka_title as woka_title, a.author_name as author_name, l.language_name as language_name, b.bisac_code as bisac_code, b.bisac_value as bisac_value 
ORDER BY woka_id;
```

And I want to add more info, a description for example. I have the Description nodes created and the relationships created, were exists, between Language and Description and Description and Book (Woka).
The query below returns all descriptions as null, but only for 60 records instead of 303. This is because not all the books have a description. Execution time is still ok, 0.3 seconds.

```
MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author), 
(l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w:Woka), (b:Bisac)<-[u:INCLUDED]-(w:Woka),
(d:Description)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w) 
WHERE (a.author_name = 'Camus, Albert') 
RETURN w.woka_id as woka_id, p.publisher_name as publisher_name, w.woka_title as woka_title, a.author_name as author_name, l.language_name as language_name, b.bisac_code as bisac_code, b.bisac_value as bisac_value, d.description as description 
ORDER BY woka_id;
```

However I know that some of the records left out from the result set, the difference between 50 and 303 does have a description. I build another query using OPTIONAL, but this one (shown below) never returns, runs for ever.

```
MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author),
 (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w:Woka)-[u:INCLUDED]->(b:Bisac) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Description)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w:Woka)-[:AUTHORED]-(a:Author)  
WHERE (a.author_name = 'Camus, Albert') 
RETURN w.woka_id as woka_id, p.publisher_name as publisher_name, w.woka_title as woka_title, a.author_name as author_name, l.language_name as language_name, b.bisac_code as bisac_code, b.bisac_value as bisac_value, d.description as description 
ORDER BY woka_id;
```

Don't know how to improve the query to get optional descriptions where exists and nulls when these don't exists for the original result set of 303 records?

Comment: Why version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author), (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w)-[u:INCLUDED]->(b:Bisac) 
WHERE (a.author_name = 'Camus, Albert') 
WITH p,r,w,s,a,l,t,u,b
OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Description)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w)
RETURN w.woka_id as woka_id, p.publisher_name as publisher_name, w.woka_title as woka_title, a.author_name as author_name, l.language_name as language_name, b.bisac_code as bisac_code, b.bisac_value as bisac_value, d.description as description 
ORDER BY woka_id;
```

Comment: I'd pull up the `WHERE` before the `WITH`.

Comment: The edited version worked, returning 303 rows in 0.5 seconds. The previous one never returned. However one of these 303 rows should have a description not null but the result row has a null description. This is happening for woka_id = '97818691945290000000' The small query showing that for this the description is not null is: MATCH (d:Description)-[:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w:Woka)-[:AUTHORED]-(a:Author), (l:Language)-[:USED]-(w)-[:PUBLISHED]-(p:Publisher), (b:Bisac)-[:INCLUDED]-(w) where (d.woka_id = '97818691945290000000') return d, w, a, l, p, b;

Comment: Could you post a subset of your data where those relationships exists and there is a description for this author?

Comment: Sorry, no need to post some data, I found the error, the query should return d.description_text instead of d.description. d.description does not exists as property and this was the reason for null returns.

Answer (score 5):

I think we already had this conversation some time ago.

**you have to get down your intermediate cardinalities**

*use directions in your relationships*

*don't repeat patterns you already solved, like*

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Description)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w:Woka)-[:AUTHORED]-(a:Author)
```

should be

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Description)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w)
```

If you are matching long paths you create **a lot** of potential matches in between, **for each** of those rows the next match(es) are executed and if they create multiple rows each you get a multiplication of `rows1*rows2*rows3`

So you have to use either `DISTINCT` or an aggregation in between to get the cardinalities down as much as possible.

Just demonstrating it for your first example, once with `DISTINCT`, once with `collect`. It might not be necessary here, but it is just for demonstration as the example is small enough.

```
MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author)
WHERE (a.author_name = 'Camus, Albert') 
WITH DISTINCT w,a,p

MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w)
WITH w,a,p, collect(l) as languages

MATCH (w)-[u:INCLUDED]->(b:Bisac) 
RETURN w.woka_id as woka_id, w.woka_title as woka_title, 
       p.publisher_name as publisher_name, 
       a.author_name as author_name, 
       [l in languages | l.language_name] as language_names, 
       b.bisac_code as bisac_code, b.bisac_value as bisac_value 
ORDER BY woka_id;
```

You correctly use `OPTIONAL MATCH` but there again you have to take into consideration that potential additional row-counts are multiplicated in.

An alternative option for OPTIONAL MATCH is to use a path expression and deconstruction, e.g. for description:

```
RETURN w.woka_id as woka_id, w.woka_title as woka_title, 
       [p in ()<-[:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w) | head(nodes(p)).description] as descriptions
```

Comment: Seems that this one returns faster than the others, the number of records and the result set are correct.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @pablosaraiva's reply make sure you have an index on :Author and property `author_name`:

```
create index on :Author(author_name)
```

If this and pablo's reply don't help, please post the query plan of your query. Use `explain <myquery>` for this (assuming you're on >=2.2)

Comment: Already indexed. ON :Author(author_name) ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint)